# Displaying content from text box

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, html, visual-studio

I have created a simple cloud web role and in there an ASP.NET web form. I have a text box where I should be able to write few text and after clicking the submit button I want to display the text.Both the text box and the button are put inside a form.

Because I am very new to Viasual studio, I don't know how to display the text by writing code in C# in `aspx.cs` class

This is what I have tried:

.aspx class:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="height: 435px">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <p>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click1" Text="Button" />
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

.aspx.cs class:

```
    namespace WebRole1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            form1.InnerText = TextBox1.Text;
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Please refer to some basic tutorials first.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use thats layout

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div runat="server" ID="fix">
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
      <p>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click1" Text="Button" />
      </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

and change code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fix.InnerText = TextBox1.Text;
    }
```